# How to add the evolution of a given variable as a new variable in a R datatable?

Tags: r, datatable, data-manipulation

I have data about variables in level, that looks like that :

```
library(data.table)
> MWE <- data.table( 
+   Country=c(rep("France",10), rep("Germany",10)),
+   Variable="GDP",
+   Unit="M€ ",
+   year=as.character(seq(2010,2019)),
+   Value=rnorm(20,1,2))
> MWE
    Country Variable Unit year      Value
 1:  France      GDP  M€  2010  0.2475945
 2:  France      GDP  M€  2011 -0.1812476
 3:  France      GDP  M€  2012 -1.0828806
 4:  France      GDP  M€  2013  1.1369641
 5:  France      GDP  M€  2014  1.8484673
 6:  France      GDP  M€  2015  0.3989246
 7:  France      GDP  M€  2016  2.9233374
 8:  France      GDP  M€  2017  0.2926139
 9:  France      GDP  M€  2018 -0.2150575
10:  France      GDP  M€  2019 -5.1984673
11: Germany      GDP  M€  2010 -0.5920364
12: Germany      GDP  M€  2011  2.3122961
13: Germany      GDP  M€  2012  3.2274544
14: Germany      GDP  M€  2013  2.7092847
15: Germany      GDP  M€  2014 -3.0176760
16: Germany      GDP  M€  2015  0.7516344
17: Germany      GDP  M€  2016  1.1884167
18: Germany      GDP  M€  2017  3.6750553
19: Germany      GDP  M€  2018  2.1837976
20: Germany      GDP  M€  2019  0.4049757
```

I would like to also have the evolution from the past year as a new line for every year.

My end datatable would therefore have the double number of lines (40 here), with the last one being :

```
Country="France", "Variable"=GDP",Unit="%", year="2019", Value=Valueinlevel(2019)/ValueinLevel(2018)-1
```

I think I can get there through dcast and some complex rearranging, but I figure there might be a better way

Comment: You have two sets of years; which of them should be calculated?

Comment: I changed my MWE midway and did not do it properly. Each year is supposed to be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited for just using mutate, that way you dont have to remake the other variables:

```
df <- bind_rows(MWE, 
                MWE %>% arrange(Country, year) %>% 
                        group_by(Country) %>% 
                        mutate(Unit = "%", 
                               Value = Value/lag(Value))) 

head(df)
   Country Variable Unit year      Value
1:  France      GDP  M€  2010 -0.1619532
2:  France      GDP  M€  2011  1.8810795
3:  France      GDP  M€  2012 -2.5558978
4:  France      GDP  M€  2013  0.6677455
5:  France      GDP  M€  2014  0.4666320
6:  France      GDP  M€  2015  2.4144170
```

Comment: My MWE is a bit simplified and I actually have a lot more variables, so that actually manually recoding the variables would be tedious. Is there a way not to have to do that ? And how would it work for several countries ? I edited my MWE to reflect that

Comment: Edited, now you don't have to remake the variables.

Comment: Works fine thank you. Sole problem is the value of the first evolution for each country, which is falsely calculated whereas it should be `NA`. I can correct it by hand afterwards though

Answer (score 1):

Though this is not what you are asking, I think it makes more sense to put the evolution as a new column rather than creating new rows:

```
MWE$evolution = c(NA, MWE$Value[-1]/MWE$Value[-nrow(MWE)]-1)
head(MWE)
# Country Variable Unit year       Value  evolution
# 1:  France      GDP  M€  2010  2.25841420         NA
# 2:  France      GDP  M€  2011  1.15731238 -0.4875553
# 3:  France      GDP  M€  2012 -0.84725830 -1.7320913
```

Comment: And I can still melt it if necessary, then change my unit based on which column it was. Definitely doable

Comment: Is there a way to simply do it for each country if there are several of them ? I edit my MWE in the meantime

Answer (score 1):

So that the answer is also valid to any number of countries you can try:

```
MWE = MWE[order(MWE$Country, MWE$year),]
MWE$evolution = c(NA, MWE$Value[-1]/MWE$Value[-nrow(MWE)]-1)
MWE[c(F, as.logical(diff(as.numeric(as.factor(MWE$Country))))), "evolution"] = NA
```

Basically, make sure it is ordered by country and year. Compute the evolution in the same way as in my prior answer. Then fill with NA the first instance of every country.